# People picker and InfoPath Form webpart problem

Tags: sharepoint-2010, peoplepicker, infopath2010

I have an InfoPath form that i show in InfoPath Form webpart. The form contains a "People Picker" control and for some reason it never appears on InfoPath Form webpart !
The account I'm using for testing have all permissions.

Answer (score 0):

problem resolved. there was a rule that prevents the control from functioning properly.

if you came across the same issue, check your form rules.